# Why is my debugger not capable of showing my variables?

Tags: c#, debugging

I have a base class, called `Telegram`, and I would like to translate a string into a list of such telegrams.

Therefore I have the following piece of code:

```
private IEnumerable<Telegram> ExtractTelegrams(string telegramString)
{
    var telegramArray = telegramString.Split(new char[] { "\u0003", "\u0006" }, 
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (var currentTelegram in telegramArray)
    {
        ... <=== here I set my breakpoint
```

I know this code mostly works (it's been thouroughly tested), but now I'm having an extra look and I'm trying to debug that piece of code, but that's not working: this is the message in my immediate window:

```
? telegramArray
error CS0103: The name 'telegramArray' does not exist in the current context
? currentTelegram
error CS0103: The name 'currentTelegram' does not exist in the current context
```

Why is this? I'm working with "Debug" build of my application, and that `telegramArray` and `currentTelegram` are used afterwards. I know from the runtime that it works but I can't see in the debugger WHY it works. Are there problems with the `var` keyword, the `private` keyword, ...

Comment: where _exactly_ did you set your breakpoint?

Comment: This might be obvious, but did you break your application? And that your method is selected in the callstack?

Comment: If you want to see the contents of `telegramArray` when executing outside of your `ExtractTelegrams` method, you'll have to define the variable at the class level.

Comment: Meanwhile I've shown where I set my breakpoint, I've cleaned and rebuilt my application, but the problem remains. I'll continue deleting  `*.obj` files and `bin` directories in case some things keep on hanging there.

Comment: How do Autos, Locals and Modules windows look like?

Comment: @Dominique Have you tried rebuilding the solution in Debug mode and then try?

Comment: Enable just my code to see if the sources different to the build. Options->Debugging->General->"Enable just my code"